# How to find a specific value in a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have my np array list with tuples like np.array[(0,1), (2,5),...]

Now I want to search for the index of a certain value. But I just know the left side of the tuple. The approach I have found to get the index of a value (if you have both) is the following:

```
x = np.array(list(map(lambda x: x== (2, 5), groups)))
print(np.where(x))
```

But how can I search if I only know x==(2,) but not the right number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy.where, it is preferred to use `np.nonzero` directly. I would also recommend reading up on NumPy's use of boolean masking. The answer to your question, is this:

```py
import numpy as np
i = 0  # index of number we're looking for
j = 2  # number we're looking for


mask = x[:,i] == j  # Generate a binary/boolean mask for this array and this comparison
indices = np.nonzero(mask)  # Find indices where x==(2,_)
print(indices)
```

In NumPy it's generally preferred to avoid loops like the one you use above. Instead, you should use vectorized operations. So, try to avoid the `list(map())` construction you used here.

Answer (score 1):

It might just be easier that you think.

Example:

```
# Create a sample array.
a = np.array([(0, 1), (2, 5), (3, 2), (4, 6)])

# Use slicing to return all rows, there column 0 equals 2.
(a[:,0] == 2).argmax()
>>> 1

# Test the returned index against the array to verify.
a[1]
>>> array([2, 5])
```

Another way to look at the array is shown below, and will help put the concept of rows/columns into perspective for the mentioned array:

```
>>> a

array([[0, 1],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 2],
       [4, 6]])
```